# How to give RecyclerView Adapter new data from AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, asynctaskloader

My AsyncTaskLoader is loading data from a remote server. When new data arrives, naturally a call is made to `onLoadFinished`. At this point I don't know how to give the new data to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` does not give it the new data: it simply tells it there is new data. So any advice on how I might do this? Right now the best I can think of is to create my own `setData` method in my implementation of `RecyclerView.Adapter` as

```
public void setData(List<MyObject> data){
    if(null != data && !data.isEmpty()){
      synchronized(mItems){
        mItems.clear();
        mItems.addAll(data);
      }
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
```

Is my idea the best there is? Or is there a more sound way of doing this?

Comment: I personally do like this too. I put a method to update my data into my adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Same as well even in the BaseAdapter days, I go with this route on changing the underlying dataset and just invoke notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 1):

Expose a public method in your adapter to update data.

For example, you could put it like this

```
public void updateItems(ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects) {
     this.data = myObjects;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, 
1. Re- instantiate your adapter with your new data and reset the adapter.
2. The way you do it.

I can not think of any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same issue and here is the solution what I did.
1st I passed list object from onLoadFinished and in the RecyclerViewAdapter I have created method name setCardInfoList() and there I passed this object to global List object which I define in adapter class.

> > In onLoadFinished method..

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<List<Earthquake>> loader, List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {

    if (earthquakes != null && !earthquakes.isEmpty()) {

        adapter.setCardInfoList(earthquakes);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else {
        emptyView.setText("No Earthquake Found...");
    }

}
```

> > Inside Adapter class

```
public void setCardInfoList(List<Earthquake> earthquakes){
    this.earthquakeList = earthquakes;
}
```